# preg_replace обработка replacement функцией

Tags: php

```
 $out_link = '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="go.php?url=\\1">Скачать</a>';

 $post = preg_replace('#\[link\](.+?)\[\/link\]#si', $out_link , $row);
```

как \1 обработать через base64_encode() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function b64($m)
{
  return "<a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"go.php?url=".base64_encode($m[1])."\">Скачать</a>";
}
$post=preg_replace_callback('#\[link\](.+?)\[\/link\]#si', 'b64' , $row);
//если правильно понял
```